# Unable to read JSON Data from BigQuery and display it on the Vue Web Page (Nuxt 3 & Google BigQuery)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, nuxt.js

I want to read a random data table that I created in BigQuery, to display it on my Vue page. A very simple one.

Current progress, I am able to read the json data of that table in Windows terminal from

```
rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
```

, but cannot display it on Chrome Devtools Console Tab.

Below is screenshot of windows cmd terminal which display the json data (SUCCESS)

[image: json data on windows terminal]

but on, devtools console, only this is showing up

[image: Chrome Devtools Console Tab] and nothing is showing up on the web page either.

Below is my code,

Vue page

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ data }}
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    data: () => ({
        data: '',
    }),
    
    created() {
        this.viewPTTHistory()
    },

    methods: {
        async viewPTTHistory() {
            const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            const response = await axios.get(
                '/api/viewptt',
                { headers }
            )
            this.data = response.data
            console.log(response.data)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

inside /api/viewptt

```
import { BigQuery } from "@google-cloud/bigquery"

export default defineEventHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const projectId = 'projectName'
        const datasetId = 'datasetName'
        const tableId = 'tableName'
        const bigquery = new BigQuery({
            projectId: projectId
        })
        const query = `SELECT * FROM ${projectId}.${datasetId}.${tableId}`
        const options = {
            query: query,
            location: 'asia-southeast1'
        }

        const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
        const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
        rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

I'm using Nuxt 3 and Google BigQuery.

Expected Outcome: the json data that display on windows terminal, should be able to display in the webpage and chrome devtools console tab too.

Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What heppens when you open http://localhost:3000/api/viewptt in your browser?

Comment: {"url":"/api/viewptt","statusCode":404,"statusMessage":"Cannot find any route matching /api/viewptt.","message":"Cannot find any route matching /api/viewptt.","stack":""}

Comment: above 'texts' shows up on the page @AndreyBessonov

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

So, solved the issue. I forgot to add `return rows;` which returns the query results. Here is the updated code if somebody might need it later

vue page

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ data }}
        <div v-if="data === ''">Data is empty</div>
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => ({
        data: '',
    }),
    
    created() {
        this.viewPTTHistory()
    },

    methods: {
        async viewPTTHistory() {
            console.log('Fetching data from API endpoint...')
            const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            const response = await fetch(
                '/api/viewptt',
                { headers }
            )
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            console.log('Received API response:', jsonData);
            this.data = jsonData;
            console.log('Data:', this.data);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

in /api/viewptt.js/

```
import { BigQuery } from "@google-cloud/bigquery"

export default defineEventHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const projectId = 'sir-adley'
        const datasetId = 'pretask'
        const tableId = 'pretask'
        const bigquery = new BigQuery({
            projectId: projectId
        })
        const query = `SELECT * FROM ${projectId}.${datasetId}.${tableId}`
        const options = {
            query: query,
            location: 'asia-southeast1'
        }

        const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
        const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
        rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
        return rows;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

so now I can display the JSON data on my vue page.

sharing the screenshot for it

[json data on vue page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH7j2.png)

silly mistakes haha